# How do I insert values from another table and inserting a new value?

Tags: database, sql-server-2014

This is my query but it creates a new row and the only value is from the next insert query. How do I combine them? Any type of response will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
INSERT INTO empAttend (empID, empLName, empFName) SELECT empID, empLName, empFName FROM emp WHERE empUser = 'name';
INSERT INTO empAttend (empTimeIn) VALUES (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `INSERT` statement creates new row(s). The best solution would be to specify all values for all columns in the single statement:

```
INSERT INTO empAttend (empID, empLName, empFName, empTimeIn) 
SELECT empID, empLName, empFName, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
FROM emp 
WHERE empUser = 'name';
```

When you cannot do the above for some reason you need to `UPDATE` the existing row(s) instead. To do this you would need to have identifying information about the row(s) you need to update, be it a (primary) key, or some other combination of column data to identify the rows.

---

Alternatively, create a default constraint on your table that populates the column when no value is provided. For example you could set the default value of `empTimeIn` to `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`, then simply omit the second statement to have this default applied. I do not know your business requirements but this may be a good option.